# React doesn't recognize function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying [this tutorial for the react chat](https://github.com/Wolox/react-chat-widget) and keep getting the error

```
TypeError: n.props.handleNewUserMessage is not a function
```

I tried to resolve it using the following resources:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/6fd6nl/keep_getting_error_thispropsonsearch_in_not_a/?st=jhiugk4d&sh=fabd3cc4
- [ReactJS with ES6: this.props is not a function when I communicate two components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141444/reactjs-with-es6-this-props-is-not-a-function-when-i-communicate-two-components)
- [React TypeError this._test is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872361/react-typeerror-this-test-is-not-a-function)
- [React does not recognize my function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45746851/react-does-not-recognize-my-function)

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Widget, addResponseMessage } from 'react-chat-widget';
import 'react-chat-widget/lib/styles.css';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    addResponseMessage("How can I help you?");
  }

  handleNewUserMessage = (newMessage) => {
    console.log(`New message incomig! ${newMessage}`);
    // Now send the message throught the backend API
    addResponseMessage('response');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Widget />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: handleNewUserMessage where do you use this function? You showed it's declaration, but I don't see where you use it, and the error is about this method. Looks like you should've done this 
<Widget
          handleNewUserMessage={this.handleNewUserMessage}
        />

Comment: Where are u calling handleNewUserMessage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as the error mentions, you forgot to actually add the method to the props:

```
 <Widget
    handleNewUserMessage={this.handleNewUserMessage}
 />
```